# Android_Studio (Basics) – How can i delete a button, that the button-string will also be removed?

Tags: android, android-studio, shortcut

If I delete a button, the button's string will not be deleted.

Is there a short-cut to automatically delete the string resource when I delete the button?

i.e.

If i delete this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:text="@string/lö" />
```

I want that this line in my "string.xml" to be automatically delete:

```
<string name="lö">asfd</string>
```

Comment: this is not possible. Both are independent. We define string in strings.xml so that we can reuse the string in more than one places

Comment: It is also not logical. As let us say, you declare a string named "Submit", it can be used at multiple places. Hence, it is not known to android in that layout whether it is being referenced or not and so cannot be and should not be deleted.

Comment: Gotta edit the code of intelliJ IDEA man.